# SAML HTTPS connection with kennisnet staging environment

Tags: spring-saml

I took sample webapp from https://github.com/vdenotaris/spring-boot-security-saml-sample and it is working file. Later. I tried to connect kennisnet staging environment.

Kennisnet details here

https://developers.wiki.kennisnet.nl/index.php?title=KNF:Hoofdpagina/en

I updated metadata which is downloadable from this url https://hub-s.entree.kennisnet.nl/openaselect/profiles/saml2/

I generated smalKeyStore.jks using below commands

1. keytool -genkey -alias tomcat -keyalg RSA -keystore samlKeyStore.jks
2. keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore samlKeyStore.jks -destkeystore
       samlKeyStore.jks -deststoretype pkcs12

I followed all Spring SAML https threads in stackoverflow and not able to figure it out this issue.

LOGS:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add the certificate to your JDK so that your application can get the metadata from URL https://aselect-s.entree.kennisnet.nl/openaselect/profiles/saml2.

These are the steps you need to fillow:

1. Download the certificate for **aselect-s.entree.kennisnet.nl**
2. Import the certificate to your JDK/JRE using this command:

   keytool -keystore #path to java_home#/lib/security/cacerts -importcert -alias #anything relevent# -file #path to certificate#

Make sure your server is using same java_home where you are importing the certificate, also verify the subjectname in the certificate before importing, it must be **"CN = *.entree.kennisnet.nl"**

3. Restart the server.

Comment: NO. Still not working. I did as per your steps. still same error. I copied x509 certificate in cert file and run keytool command.

Comment: Can you double check that the server running your application using same java where you imported the certificate?

Comment: Also repeat the same steps but this time install the certificate to your SAML keystore instead of java default keystore.

Comment: As per this link https://docs.spring.io/spring-security-saml/docs/1.0.0.RC3-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/chapter-configuration.html#configuration-metadata , I need to handover metadata url of my service to kennisnet then we can able to interact with kennisnet. My POC code is here. https://github.com/GangadharBommasani/spring-kennisnet-saml